# Two polynomials sharing two values

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Let $f, g \colon \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ be two nonconstant polynomial functions such that
$$f(x) = 1 \iff g(x)=1$$
and
$$f(x) = 0 \iff g(x)=0.$$

Does it imply that $f \equiv g$, that is, they come from the same polynomial? This is certainly not true for real polynomials, as an example of $g(x) = f(x)^3 = x^3$ shows.

If possible, I would like to know about generalisations to fields other than $\mathbb C$ - I couldn't find any reference in literature.